# CSS Sprites and tabs menu nav style issues

Tags: css

I am currently using a sprite image for my tabs menu. The problem is that the images are showing but the title of each tab is not appearing at all. How can place the image and title inside the tab nicely? [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/test1.php)

This what I am aiming for:

[image]

This what I am getting:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#tab-1" class="pngIcon sprite-category">1. Category</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-2" class="pngIcon sprite-description">2. Description</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-3" class="pngIcon sprite-images">3. Images</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-4" class="pngIcon sprite-contact">4. Contact Info</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-5" class="pngIcon sprite-final">5. Final</a></li>
</ul>
```

**postingtabs.css**

```
.pngIcon {
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/images/tabdetails.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-indent: 40px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Just delete `width` on `.sprite-*` selectors in your css file :

**Your css:**

```
.sprite-final{  background-position: 0 0; width: 32px; height: 32px; } 
.sprite-category{ background-position: 0 -82px; width: 32px; height: 32px; } 
.sprite-contact{ background-position: 0 -164px; width: 32px; height: 32px; } 
.sprite-description{ background-position: 0 -246px; width: 32px; height: 32px; } 
.sprite-images{ background-position: 0 -328px; width: 32px; height: 32px; }
```

**Working css:**

```
.sprite-final{  background-position: 0 0; height: 32px; } 
.sprite-category{ background-position: 0 -82px; height: 32px; } 
.sprite-contact{ background-position: 0 -164px; height: 32px; } 
.sprite-description{ background-position: 0 -246px; height: 32px; } 
.sprite-images{ background-position: 0 -328px; height: 32px; }
```

### Final Result: [**demo on dabblet**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3244655)

[image]

**CSS code:** (I have made some refactoring)

```
li a {
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/images/tabdetails.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-indent: 40px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-category    { background-position: 0px -85px; }
.nav-description { background-position: 0px -248px; }
.nav-images      { background-position: 0px -327px; }
.nav-contact     { background-position: 0px -164px; }
.nav-final       { background-position: 0px 0px; }
```

Comment: Absolutely Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not declaring your element's width seems to be your immediate issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `width: auto` to your CSS (thanks Kwon for pointing out the problem). Working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HdekX/).

```
.pngIcon {
    ...
    width: auto;
}
```